# Не работает метод, открывающий файл в Android

Tags: java, android

Снова не могу найти ошибку, в этот раз, подозреваю, что я как-то не так прописала путь к файлу, потому что условие if(file.exists() && file.isFile()) никогда не выполняется

Путь:

```
private String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/files/";
```

В манифесте прописано:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Кнопка "открыть файл":

```
 case R.id.action_open:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Имя файла");
                builder.setMessage("Введите имя файла для открытия");
                EditText input = new EditText(this); //ввод имени файла
                builder.setView(input);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Открыть", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        editText.setText("");
                        String value = input.getText().toString(); 
                        filename = value;
                        File file = new File(path + filename);
                        if(file.exists() && file.isFile()) {
                            editText.setText(openFile(filename));
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Файл не существует.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
                return true;
```

Метод, открывающий файл:

```
private String openFile(AppCompatActivity app, String filename) {

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            File file = new File((this.path), filename);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;
            while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                text.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return text.toString();
    }
```

Я знаю, что есть Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, но не понимаю, как с ним работать (если это является решением проблемы, то можно, пожалуйста, ссылку на какой-нибудь пример?)
Я не понимаю сам принцип работы - мы при помощи uri однозначно определяем файл, передаем его uri в метод, дальше создается конкретный intent, определяется категория и тип, и все это передается в startActivityForResult(). А затем используется onActivityResult и каким-то образом получается ссылка на файл?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
разрешение на чтение есть? а то вы написали, что у вас только на "запись" дано.

Comment: и под какое API Android пишите? в последних версиях одними uses-permission для чтения пользовательских данных не обойтись. надо еще доп.код на разрешение писать.

Comment: да,  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> там тоже есть. Минимальный API 16, максимальный - API 30

Comment: у меня есть кусок кода, отвечающий за разрешение на доступ к медиафайлам (он сюда просто не влезет, но в кратце он запрашивает разрешение на работу с медиафайлами, если оно дано, то можно работать, если нет - выход из приложения или переход в настройки)

Comment: попробуйте в Манифесте после application добавить
  <application>
  android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
вообще, это костыль. но так хотя бы попытаетесь найти причину неполадки: в коде или в доступе к файлам.

Comment: еще есть идея, но она маловероятная...
выведите в лог и посмотрите как выглядит ваш path.
может быть Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() возвращает вам ...fold/
и когда вы потом плюсуете + "/files/" вы получаете 
...fold//files/ - 2 знака '//' и из-за этого ошибка

Comment: android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"  не помогло, как и просто написать "files/"

Comment: по debug видно, что путь - "storage/emulated/0files/" (этот 0 должен быть? я не вписывала его в саму переменную path)

Comment: Должен, раз есть - но после него должен быть сепаратор: `"storage/emulated/0/files/"`. Думаю проблема была в том, что папка `files` не существует и вы её не создаёте - в остальном код рабочий до Андроид 11.

Comment: попробуйте заменить File file = new File(path + filename); на File file = new File(path,  filename);